# Не вызывается деструктор при освобождении памяти от указателей на обьекты

Tags: c++

```
std::cout << "Set range: ";
std::cin >> range;

shape **shapes_list = new shape*[range];

while (i != range)
{
    shapes_list[i] = ShapeFactory::createShape(type);
    i++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < range; ++i)
{
    shapes_list[i]->create();
}
```

Когда здесь освобождаю память деструкторы обьектов не вызываются

```
for (int i = 0; i < range; ++i) {
    delete [] shapes_list[i];
}
delete [] shapes_list;
```

А здесь нормально вызывается

```
shape* s = ShapeFactory::createShape(1);
delete s;
```

Comment: а зачем квадратные скобки в цикле?

Comment: std::vector/unuque_ptr запрещено использовать?

Comment: надо было использовать только массив ... я исправил спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
delete [] shapes_list[i];
```

замените на

```
delete shapes_list[i];
```

Со скобочками нужен только для самого shapes_list

Comment: спасибо большое сработало )))